# set style with :hover javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, stylesheet

I understand that the following method is great for setting CSS styles because of browser compatibility.

```
element.style.cssText = "color:red;";
```

What I can't do is use `cssText` to apply styles on the `:hover` and `:focus` CSS events.

What do I do instead of this?

```
element.style.cssText = ":focus{color:red;}";
```

P.S. Don't mention using javascript events such as `onmouseover` instead of the CSS `:hover` ( It doesn't fit my situation.)

Comment: `onmouseover` is the same as `hover`; you can attach that event and simply add a class, and via CSS style that class. Has higher reusability.

Comment: Why just don't define it in a normal css and change only class in javascript?

Comment: @Zirak, almost. `:hover` works only on `<a>` tags in IE6, but `onmouseover` works on virtually all of the elements. They are similar, but not the same.

Comment: @Zirak , and @Dmitry those two options are not available in this circumstance. Do you know a method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it with some Voodoo magic:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style = document.createElement('style');
var declarations = document.createTextNode('selector:pseudo { property: value }');

style.type = 'text/css';

if (style.styleSheet) {
  style.styleSheet.cssText = declarations.nodeValue;
} else {
  style.appendChild(declarations);
}

head.appendChild(style);
```

Not exactly what you needed, but you can tweak it and make a fancy function out of it if you want.

Comment: What is "Voodoo magic"? Please explain. I sure don't like the connotations.

Answer (score 2):

You could always add an individual style rule to an existing style sheet, instead of creating a new style element. Something along the lines of:

```js
function addStyle() {
    var style = document.styleSheets[0];        //select style sheet (0==first)
    var styleSel = ".class:hover";              //define selector
    var styleDec = "color: red;";             //define declaration

    if(style.insertRule) {        //for modern, DOM-compliant browsers

        style.insertRule(styleSel+'{'+styleDec+'}', style.cssRules.length);
        //I chose to do it this way to more easily support the addRule method, but
        //know that insertRule only needs two parameters, full style rule
        //(selector+prop/value declarations), and index to insert rule at
        //                  styleSheets[0].insertRule(rule, index);

    }else {                       //for IE < 9
        style.addRule(styleSel, styleDec, -1);
    }
}
```

I adapted the [example at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule)
This assumes you are using a class (that is already defined and applied) to add the :hover pseudo-selector to, but it could just as easily be an ID or element selector.
 If you were unable to add a class or style rule beforehand, you could also do that dynamically in much the same way (define class, define class:hover, then apply class to desired elements).